# Play Framework - how to get a value from a function in a Scala template?

Tags: playframework-2.0, twirl

So I have this code (all of this is in the one scala.html file):

```
@getLevelAsRoman(level: Integer) : String = @{
 @if(level == 1){ 
    @return "I"
 }
 @if(level == 2){ 
    @return "II"
 }
 @if(level == 3){ 
    @return "III"
 }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
@{move.getMove.getName + " " + getLevelAsRoman(move.getMoveLevel) }
```

I just want to show the value in my html. How am I meant to do this? The above code gets the error

```
identifier expected but 'if' found.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
@getLevelAsRoman(level: Integer): String = @{  
    if(level == 1){ 
        "I"
    } else if(level == 2){ 
        "II"
    } else if(level == 3){ 
        "III"
    } else {
        "default"
    }
}
```